# Why isn't the hover working on child but parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want some action to be performed when the child element **.menuitems** is hovered. Currently I've replaced the action with an **alert** to make it simple.
Now the problem is that when I use selector ("**#result_row .menuitems**"), nothing works. But if I use ("**#result_row**"), it works fine i.e., alert works.

Why is it so? It should work in both cases? I want the hover to work on child as well as grandchilds (.menu1).

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="result_row"><div class="menuitems">
    <div class="menu1">sfsdsf<span id="srno">4</span></div>
    <div class="menu2">sfsdfs@saf</div>
    <div class="menu3">sdfsdf<span id="cross">X</span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menuitems{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #007fad;
}
.resultmenu > .menuitems{
    background: #004068;
}
.menuitems div{
    background: #00aeef;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.menu1{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.menu2{
    float: left;
    width: 40.4%;
}
.menu3{
    float: right;
    width: 34%;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result_row .menuitems").hover(function(){
        //var tarparent=$(event.target).parent().find("#cross");
        //$(tarparent).toggle();
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

NOTE: This code won't render fine as it is missing many other styles, parent elements etc. So I've put a screenshot to describe the problem.

[image]

Red rectangle is **.result_row**. Green is child, **.menuitems**.

**EDIT:**
If you want to know something else, here it is: when I use .menuitems:hover in CSS (not jQuery), the hover works.

**EDIT2:**

One more thing that can be important to you while answering is: The window "EMAIL" you're seing in this image is no loaded when open the main page(site). It is loaded only when I click a button on the page, and the content you're seeing in 2nd and 3rd row are loaded ALONG WITH IT, i.e., they're not static!

Comment: First off, take the `alert()` out and use `console.log()` and look in the console.  The `alert()` itself interferes with your ability to see what's going on.

Comment: Missing a div for <div class="menuitems"> ?

Comment: That's not the problem. I pasted it incorrect. I've edited it though.

Comment: console.log doesn't print anything.

Comment: Can you verify your JavaScript is actually being executed? (such as putting a console.log inside your ready function to show that the hover is being applied)

Comment: JavaScript is working fine except when the selector is changed to child.

Answer (score 0):

I entered everything you had into jsfiddle and it worked (hit F12 to see console.log)

https://jsfiddle.net/bLjmocza/

I also replaced

```
$("#result_row .menuitems").hover(function(){
```

with

```
$(".menuitems").hover(function(){
```

as that seemed to be more what you were trying to achieve in the first place

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result_row .menuitems").mouseover(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `float` in your CSS. See: http://wtfhtmlcss.com/#floats-computed-height.

The quick and diry fix ist to float the parent. But you are better off applying a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to the parent. The added bonus is you can then get rid of your `clear` div.

Below is clearfix option:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result_row .menuitems").hover(function(){
        //var tarparent=$(event.target).parent().find("#cross");
        //$(tarparent).toggle();
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

```css
.menuitems{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #007fad;
}
.resultmenu > .menuitems{
    background: #004068;
}
.menuitems div{
    background: #00aeef;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    position: relative;

}
.menu1{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.menu2{
    float: left;
    width: 40.4%;
}
.menu3{
    float: right;
    width: 34%;
}


.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result_row"><div class="menuitems clearfix">
    <div class="menu1">sfsdsf<span id="srno">4</span></div>
    <div class="menu2">sfsdfs@saf</div>
    <div class="menu3">sdfsdf<span id="cross">X</span></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. I understood what's written about compound height. But where do you want me to add clearfix?

Comment: Secondly, these floated elements already have height, don't they?

Comment: Did you read EDIT2?. It's not working even when I added float: left.

Comment: Add the clearfix to the parent element: `.menuitems`. The floated elements have a height but the parent (`.menuitems`) does not. Try adding a boarder to `.menuitems` without floating it or adding a clearfix and see what (doesn't) happen.

Comment: Ok let me try. Meanwhile could you tell me how to highlight a class like you've done in above comment?

Comment: Did you run my snippet? Adding float left to `.menuitems` works with the code as you supplied it. as to why the CSS :hover works is that I that with CSS if you hover the children, you also hover the parent. On the side note, surround what you want to highlite as code with back-ticks `

Comment: I tried but it just collpases all menus. And hover still doesn't work.

Comment: 'this' is backtick

Comment: And the parent has already height. I checked it applying border.

Comment: I got it. The problem is not with float or clearfix. You might not see the height because it is missing some CSS. Let me assure you. Did you read my 2nd edit? The problem is because of that. I just manually added a .menuitems div and it works. But it doesn't work with the .menuitems that are loaded by clicking a button.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see. New answer with new jquery coming up!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated: This won't work in jQuery 1.9 onwards!**

http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes. Use mouseenter/mouseleave instead

A second anser as this one addresses binding handlers to dynamic elements

As you are dynamically adding elements to the page you want to use jquery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

Change gour jquery to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result_row").on(".menuitems", "hover", function(){
        //var tarparent=$(event.target).parent().find("#cross");
        //$(tarparent).toggle();
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

The main difference is this will attatch the hover event handler any child of `resultrow` with a class of `menuitems` that exist now or that are added later.

Comment: I think you need to make a new question with code that demonstrates how you add the extra items. Make a small demonstration that replicates the problem.

Comment: Ahh wait... are you adding a new `#result_row` each time? If so there are 2 problems here. 1) ID needs to be unique. Don't add new elements with duplicate IDs. 2) `on` wont work as I have shown, we need to "bind" it to a static element, like the parent of `#result_row`

Comment: Let me check. Well problem 2 doesn't exist. The rows are added at once. It's like a separate html document.

Comment: Problem 2 still extists, just in a slightly different context. Find a static object to attatch `on` to, then use the first parameter to select the dynamic child elements. I'm still going to suggest a new question which demonstrates more of your problem.

Comment: I changed the element to the main container which is loaded automatically at the start, so its static. But it doesn't work. what do I do?

Comment: Listen. I changed the hover to mouseover (also mouseenter) and it works in both cases except hover. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117569/discussion-between-jon-p-and-vikas-kumar).